# Rewrite rules are not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using wamp (localhost) and my rewrite rule is not working. I tried searching for the solution but couldn't find anything that would work.

What I want to do is I want to let the users type in

```
localhost/example/user1
```

and i want the server to show them the profile of user1. That is, i want the server to collect the data from

```
localhost/example/group.php?u=user1
```

when the user types the first url.

That is when the user types in,

```
localhost/example/user1
```

the user should get to see the profile of user1.

Now i have used the following code to make it work. But it says

> The requested URL /example/user1 was not found on this server.

Though the account exists.

my .htaccess file is inside the localhost/example directory.
I have tried placing it in the root directory. I have tried adding the following line

```
RewriteBase /example/
```

after

```
RewriteEngine On
```

But nothing seems to work.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ group.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ group.php?u=$1
```

Comment: yes I did verify that....and ya it is working. @anubhava

Comment: The error learns us that the rule is not executed, or that the regex does not match whatever is in the first argument. If the rule was executed, but the rewritten file didn't exist you would get the error "The requested URL /example/group.php was not found on this server." You can test if anything is happening by puting the following rule in the .htaccess in your example directory: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /donotmatchthis/$1 [R,L]`. If you are not redirected to this url, then either your .htaccess file is not being read, or your rule is unreachable.

Comment: am getting redirected to:  http://localhost/donotmatchthis/

Comment: When you enter what url?

Comment: when i enter localhost/example/   Anyway i guess i got the error. My regex will include username with only letters and characters while my username is gonna be the format : user.name .... that is it is gonna include a "." dot. Can you help me with the regex i will need? I am a noob in regex and .htaccess so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tested your rewriterule with a different username than your question suggests, it is likely that the regex is incorrect. Don't try to match every character that can possibly in your username. Exclude the character that cannot be in the username instead, the slash character.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ group.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: but then for this, it gives "User doesnt exist" for even localhost/example and for every other url.

Comment: You didn't put it in the .htaccess in your example folder?

Comment: yes i did. But that i am getting "user doesn't exist" no matter what i type now.

Comment: `http://localhost/example` CANNOT match this rule if it is in a `.htaccess` file in a folder `example`. The rule must match at least 1 character, and even if Apache adds a `/` for you, it would match an empty string. I suppose `user doesn't exist` is a message from group.php? Go forth and debug that then...

Comment: Heyy! thanx a lot...i figured out the error, that is because, it is treating my files such as index.php and xyz.php as username as well...that is why am getting user doesn't exist all the time.

I just wanted to ask one last question, how can i skip these these: index.php and xyz.php and get the desired result. 

Thanx a lot...am new to .htaccess and regex!

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$`

Comment: Heyy @Sumurai8 ....i wanted to ask, one more thing...it is that...i want to redirect the url...not rewrite but redirect the url...

when the user types in wwww.example.com/user1/ ... i want to direct the user to www.example.com/user1 

that is...i want to redirect this format www.example.com/user1(n number of slashes) to www.example.com/user1...

Comment: 2 or more slashes are automatically truncated to one slash by any browser I know. No need to have a rule for that.